# Align content to center with variant as caption in Material UI Typography

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, typography

I have two Typography elements with default and caption variants. How do I center the content with `align="center"` property with variant as caption as this doesn't seem to work.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography align="center">Centered text</Typography>
        <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="caption" align="center">A Caption!</Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I created a working example using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typography-variants?file=index.js). Could anyone please help?

Comment: `variant="caption" ` is belongs to span thats why its not working

Comment: @RajKumar Got it! Figured a way by wrapping the element in a `Box` and style my component.

Answer (score 7):

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function DisableElevation() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography align="center">Centered text</Typography>
      <Typography
        display="block"
        color="textSecondary"
        variant="caption"
        align="center"
      >
        A Caption!
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: display="block" was the thing. THANK YOU!